# Why don't my low-voltage LED lights work without an incandescent?

Tags: lighting, led, low-voltage

I have three T3 puck lights on each side of my kitchen under my cabinets. The 3 for each side are powered by a 12V supply (2 supplies) from the basement and each individually have a low voltage wire to the light from the supply. The T3 incandescent bulbs throw off a lot of heat and I want to change to LED to reduce the heat into the bottom shelf of the cabinets. When I changed all the bulbs to the 20w equivalent Feit warm light bulbs from Menards (sku 3538886) and they flash on momentarily then stay off with the switch on. I replaced one of the LEDs with an incandescent and then all three lights on that circuit come on (2 led, 1 incandescent). What is the issue causing the LEDs to go out without an incandescent working in the circuit?[image]

Comment: Is the switch on the 120V or the 12V side? Is the switch anything fancy (lighted, timer, etc.)?

Comment: There are dozens of questions about this at this site, did you search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformer that supplies the 12v isn't rated to drive a low load because it was designed to drive a incandescent and supply no power when the current is below some threshold.

This is a common issue with older low voltage supplies. To fix that you will need to either keep a incandescent in one of the sockets, or you need to replace the supply with one that can drive a <2W load.

Comment: Or upgrade to a newer supply that will work with LEDs, or add more lights to increase the load to meet the supply's minimum requirements...

Comment: So since I had two transformers in adjacent outlets in the basement, I eliminated one of them and tied all six into one. That did the trick to raise the load so they all work off the same transformer now. 
I did search before posting and didn’t see any that hit my problem with a solid solution on the head. Thanks for the help on this one!